# Finding the range of a function given a specific domain

Tags: functions

The question is to "Find the range of each function over the given domain $f(x) = 1 / (2x + 5)$ for $-2 \le x \le 2$.

I'm not sure what this is asking me to do , specifically the part over the given domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General terminology:

- Domain: all possible values of $x$
- Range: all possible values of $f(x)$

---

Specific solution:

- Domain: $-2 \leq x \leq 2$
- Range: $\frac{1}{9} \leq f(x) \leq 1$

Comment: How did you arrive at the values for the solution of the range?

Comment: @Ishamel: In the given domain, the function is continuous **and** monotonously decreasing. So I just calculated the value of the function at the end-points. In other words, I calculated $f(-2)$ and $f(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

They are asking you how $f(x)$ varies when $x$ varies in the range $[-2\ , 2]$.